# Absolute Continuity of $(X+Y, Z)$ where $X \perp Y, Z$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-measure, absolute-continuity

Let $X$ be an absolutely continuous $n_1$-dimensional random variable which is independent from $Y, Z$ where are $n_1$- and $n_2$-dimensional random variables, respectively. Further, assume $Z$ is an absolutely continuous random variable ($Y$ have singularities and is dependent on $Z$). How do we prove that $(X+Y, Z)$ is also absolutely continuous?

Comment: What is your work on this subject ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Actually, I am looking for a generalization on the fact that sum of every absolutely continuous random variable and an independent random variable is also absolutely continuous. This helps me solve a problem in compressibility of a random source.